# Ruby GUI support on OSX Mavericks (Not Shoes or Ruby Motion) plus OSX app package support

Tags: ruby, user-interface, osx-mavericks

This has been asked many times. Some of the answers are pretty old now. I have looked around everywhere for 2 things.This the last resort before I give up. Looking for:

- Bindings that will enable GUI programming using Ruby (not [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com)) using Mavericks. I have found plenty bindings but with no activity for the past 3 or 4 years, with the exception of [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com) which seems very expensive while not taking advantage of Xcode features / does not have an IDE.
- Way to package app for users as a regular OSX app so the user does not have to install anything by hand on OSX (if mutiplatform even better to target Windows too)

I have fallen in love with Ruby but without a means to tackle the above will be difficult to deploy for users, while I am not interested in Rails. 
Feels like Rails popularity has in effect killed Ruby by putting it into a niche when it could be so much more.

Any new news on either of these 2 fronts or everything is abandoned / dead ? 
Should I move on with Python / Objective-C ? (Which I like both but enjoy Ruby more)

Answer (score 2):

I succesfully compiled scripts with tk, green shoes and gosu as a GUI to an executable with ocra but only have experience doing so on windows. If you want an actual, cross platform GUI try the java swing framework with jruby, here an example.
If you deploy a JAR or an executable nu further installations are needed.
I suppose you use MRI ruby now, the step to jruby is not so difficult.

```
require 'java'

# With the 'require' above, we can now refer to things that are part of the
# standard Java platform via their full paths.
frame = javax.swing.JFrame.new("Window") # Creating a Java JFrame
label = javax.swing.JLabel.new("Hello")

# We can transparently call Java methods on Java objects, just as if they were defined in Ruby.
frame.getContentPane.add(label)  # Invoking the Java method 'getContentPane'.
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame::EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
frame.pack
frame.setVisible(true)
```

Comment: Thank you. Explored jruby but not deep enough. Not very knowledgeable of the java swing framework but will try out a few small examples. Interesting as it can solve the 2 issues. GUI + JAR. Will give it a try.

Comment: i use warble to jar-up my jruby scripts

Answer (score 2):

[RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com) is the best alternative. But if don't want to spend the money you should be able to use macruby.

Here are some resources

http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/03/12/creating-our-very-first-mac-application-with-ruby-how-exciting/

I must say that using macruby for a big project might not be a good idea. You should expect stuff breaking and few support. As of 2015, the [MacRuby page on GitHub][3] says that the project is in an indefinite hiatus due to the changes made by Apple in the Objective C garbage collection support that MacRuby depends on. They suggest using RubyMotion.

RubyMotion seems to be really good for what you want but for development the lack of a IDE is really a huge downside. Also from my experience rubymotion only comes handy if you already know the cocoa framework really well.

So my recommendation is for you to test rubymotion if you can. They give your money back in the first 30 days if you only want to try it out. So if you have the money give it a try.

If you are new to osx development and only want to develop for osx I think you should go with objective-c. The language is not that bad and you will get the best development environment available for it for free.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I know the Cocoa framework and currently develop using Objective-C so not problem on that front. Will check macruby with a small test project. Just checking to be sure nothing new in the pipeline I might have missed. As you said the problem with Ruby Motion is not having and IDE while today I enjoy for free very good one.